# ALLOWED_HOSTS doesn't accept IP Address?

Tags: django, django-settings

Within my settings.py file, when I use ALLOWED_HOSTS of either my domain name or '*', I'm able to access my website. When I indicate only my server's static IP address, I get a 400 Bad Request error. Based on what I've read, this should work. Any thoughts as to why it might not be working?

I should mention that my site will be hosting a chaning list of domains, so it's important that I be able to use IP address in allowed hosts as opposed to a list of domain names.

Thanks

Comment: and can you show how you are passing the ip address?

Comment: That will not work - ALLOWED_HOSTS is meant specifically to prevent against HTTP HOST header attacks - the whole point of it is to ensure that only hostnames you allow can access the site. Putting an IP in there will not help if you still want to access that IP using different host names.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there a way to import a list of hosts into allowed_hosts from a text file that is in the settings directory?

Comment: Sure - you'd just have to open and parse the file in Python and then put the contents into the setting.